# Interthread communication between 2 Java Projects

Tags: java, ipc

I want to interthread communication 2 java projects . How can I do this? Java using IPC? and then threads messaging on each one .

Comment: Interthread or interprocess?

Comment: interthread . communicate of projects threads

Comment: You seem to be confused between _inter_thread _intra_application communication and _inter_application communication. Further, this question is **far** too broad - there are an almost infinite number of ways to do this; from the basic (file) to the advanced (sockets).

Comment: There are 2 projects and there are threads of projects .I know I must use to socket ,ipc but ı dont know path

Comment: Do you have document about this ?

Comment: What do you mean with "projects"? Do you mean you have one process with multiple threads and want to share data among them? In that case, they all share the same address space already. Otherwise, you need IPC (file, sockets, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand correctly what you need.
Have a look at [RMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) or [JMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service).

Both are APIs of Java EE and application servers like WebLogic or WildFly implement them out of the box.

RMI is the Remote Method Invocation API which is primarily used when one Java application running in a JVM provides services to other Java applications (running in separate JVMs). The client applications do not need to know the implementation of the services, just their interfaces.

JMS (Java Message Service) can be used in a single Java application or across multiple applications to provide asynchronous point-to-point (Queue in JMS terminology) or publish/subscribe (Topic in JMS terminology) type of communication between components.

Comment: There are one pc in here.Projects in same machine.RMİ work here?